# Possible to have multiple select statement in a view? Or what should it be?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is it possible to have multiple select statements within a view based on user permission?  Or what should be good practice?
I would like to have a view that only show the data based on user permission.  The view going to have code  **USER_ID = (SELECT SYSTEM_USER)** I planned to use Windows Authentication.

I expect user abc@company.com to see all the data from TRANS table, user def@company.com only sees data based on SUPERVISOR'S QUERY and user ghi@company.com can see all data based on USER'S QUERY.

MANAGER'S QUERY

```
    SELECT OrderNum, total, CustomerNum, Invoice, Order_Date, Region   FROM TRANS
```

SUPERVISOR'S QUERY

```
    SELECT OrderNum, total, Invoice, Order_Date, Region   FROM TRANS
```

USER'S QUERY

```
    SELECT OrderNum, total, Order_Date, Region   FROM TRANS
    WHERE only allow user to see the region assigned to them, example user with Region_N in 
    PERM_GROUP from Table: EMPLOYEE should only see data in Region "N"
```

Table:  EMPLOYEE

```
         USER_ID        |     PERM_GROUP     
    --------------------------------------
    abc@company.com     |  Manager   
    def@company.com     |  Supervisor
    ghi@company.com     |  User; Region_N
```

Table:  TRANS

```
    OrderNum  |  Total  | CustomerNum | Invoice |  Order_Date  |  Region  
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    25986     |  100    |  Yahoo123   | ad589   |  10-28-12    |  N
    87456     |  700    |  Google856  | cb124   |  05-17-12    |  E
    30123     |  450    |  MSN907     | ab456   |  01-22-10    |  S
```

Comment: This sounds like you're talking about [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15). If so, it has nothing to do with Views.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I'm not sure what would be the best practice since I'm new to SQL, I read about predicate function, but not sure how is that fit on what I wanted to do.

Comment: You can combine the results of `select` statements with `union all`. In some projects I've created table-valued functions (TVFs) that take a `UserId` and return the regions/departments/cities/... that the user has access to or authority over. The result of the TVF can be used in a `join` or `where` to filter the data appropriately. Aside: If you're storing delimited strings, e.g. `'User; Region_N'`, you're on the wrong track.

Comment: Thanks @HABO, could you give me an example?  I'm not sure I understand your above comment.

Comment: Something like `create function UserRegionAccess( @UserId as Int ) returns table return select RegionId from UserRegions where UserId = @UserId union select RegionId from Regions where exists ( select 42 from Administrators where UserId = @UserId );`. Note the use of [surrogate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), i.e. `UserId` is not an email address subject to change. It is assumed that any user in `Administrators` has access to all `Regions`.

Comment: I'm going to try it out @HABO.  Thanks

Comment: @HABO, I'm lost :(